# How to turn JSON array into Postgres array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have following json array

```
{ "21553287" : [20304602], "2971244" : [20304602,21231942,21232245], "22400866" : [20304602], "22511397" : [20304602], "1800479" : [20304602], "22152979" : [20304602,21231681,21232245], "22471714" : [20304602,21231702], "22354302" : [20304602], "22363993" : [20304602], "22360635" : [20304602,21231679], "21987748" : [20304602,21379642], "21983181" : [20304602]}
```

to create this array i used

```
folders AS (
SELECT json_object_agg("Face":: text, r)  FROM (
SELECT array_agg("Folder") r, "Face" FROM "FaceFolder"

WHERE "Type" = 7 AND "Face" IS NOT NULL AND  "Folder" IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY "Face") t
```

)

When tried to

```
SELECT "@Folder" WHERE "@Folder" ANY (((TABLE folders) -> (ca."@Face"::text))::text :: int[])
```

I got following error

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "[20304602,20407231]"
```

i understand that i need to make json array to postgres array but don't know how

Comment: Postgres array syntax looks like, `{20304602,20407231}`

Comment: What are you trying to do? A description of your purpose, along with sample data and desired results, would be helpful here.

Comment: @AvinKavish It's actually not, it's Pycharm standart output for postgresql

Comment: @GMB i wanna unnest json array to postgres array and find math in 'ca' table ( the contexts of this table is not important). I search and found jsonb_array_elements_text function that could help, but anyway i don't know how to implement it since i always haw different key in my json array

Comment: What language is your SELECT statement in?  It appears similar to SQL, but clearly isn't.

Comment: @jjanes I posted Postgresql tag in question)

Comment: But the query is not valid SQL for PostgreSQL.  `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"`.  It can't generate the error you show, because it is not valid syntax and so never even starts executing.  It looks like some meta-language which is supposed to be translated into real SQL by some unknown tool or preprocessor.

Comment: @AlexNikitin the error seems to be a malformation in the array literal, as I mentioned earlier a postgres array literal uses curly braces. So if you want to insert an array literal into a column, you have to use curly braces as opposed to square brackets used in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to store it as the text representation of int[] in the first place, then the cast back to int[] would work.

```
... json_object_agg("Face":: text, r::text) ...
```

Of course that makes for pretty weird JSON data if you aren't using the JSON structures throughout it.

Another option is to create a helper function to do the conversion:

```
create function json_to_intarray(json) returns int[] immutable parallel safe language SQL as $$ 
    select array_agg(x::int) from json_array_elements_text($1) f(x)
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is this dialect will work with postgresql?